# Limit $\lim_{x \to -1^+}\left({\ln(x+1)}+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

How can I calculate the following limit?

$$\lim_{x \to -1^+}\left({\ln(x+1)}+\frac{1}{x+1}\right)$$

Thanks!

Comment: use [it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Comment: How? This was my first though, but I don't know how.

Comment: Are you sure you gave the correct function? Yours is unbounded.

Comment: Generally when you try to evaluate a limit of the form $X - Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ both go to infinity, you convert the statement to $X - Y = \ln e^{X - Y} = \ln \frac {e^X} {e^Y}$ and then use l'Hopital on $\frac {e^X} {e^Y}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$e^{\ln(x+1)+\frac{1}{x+1}}= (x+1)e^{\frac{1}{x+1}}\ge(x+1)\left(1+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{2(x+1)^2}\right)=(x+1)+1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{x+1}$$

The right hand side goes to $+\infty$ if $x\rightarrow -1+$. Taking logarithms preserves the inequality since the logarithm is monotonously increasing.  We obtain

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow-1+} \left(\ln(x+1)+\frac{1}{1+x}\right)=\infty$$

Comment: Isn't $\lim_{x\to\infty}$, is $\lim_{x\to−1^+}$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla Yes, thank you. Edited.

Comment: something easy? for a student who have 16 years? thanks

Comment: @Iuli: Which step do you not understand?

Comment: $e^{x+1} \geq 1+\frac{1}{x+1}+\frac{1}{2(x+1)^2}$

Comment: @Iuli: Do you know this formula: $e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$ ? This is the definition of $e^x$. All the terms in the sum are positive so if I just sum until $n=2$, I get a smaller number than the whole sum.

Answer (score 3):

Write $\ln(1+x)$ as $-\ln\dfrac1{1+x}$ , then replace $\dfrac1{x+1}$ with $e^t$, as $t\to\infty$. You have $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}(e^t-t)$.

Answer (score 2):

One possible hint is to see that while $-1<x\leq 1$ then $$\ln|x+1|\approx x$$ so you'll get $\lim_{x\to -1^+}(x+\frac{1}{x+1})$ which is $+\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=x+1$ then
$$
\lim _{y \to 0^+} (\ln y + \frac{1}{y}) = \lim _{y \to 0^+} \frac{y\ln y + 1}{y}
$$
can you see the solution from here?

$y\ln y$ tends to zero as $y$ approaches zero (you can easily see this with de l'Hospital rule or as an application of the hierarchy of infinities); therefore you are left with $1/y$ which goes to plus infinity.

Comment: no. can you give me one more step